# Guardar imagen de formulario HTML a base de datos

Tags: html, c#, sql, mvc, asp.net-core

Estoy haciendo un formulario donde se permita registrar el nombre de la persona y guardar una foto o pdf del acta de este. Mi problema es que no sé cómo hacer que me guarde la foto a la base de datos.

He estado investigando cómo poder hacer que me guarde la foto y como utilizo la versión de net core 6, se me dificulta porque me sale utilizar funciones que solo son compatibles con las versiones antiguas y con esta no. Estoy programando en MVC.

Estos son los campos que contiene mi vista:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
      <b><label for="inputEmail5" class="form-label">Nombre</label></b>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" required>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
     <b><label for="fotoActa" class="form-label">Fotografia acta</label></b>
     <input type="file" class="form-control" name="fotoActa" id="fotoActa">
</div>
```

Esta es la tabla de la base de datos:

```
create table FotosActa
(
idFoto int identity (1,1) primary key not null,
nombre varchar(50) not null,
fotoActa image not null
)
```

Este es el procedimiento alamcenado creado en la base de datos, donde se hace el proceso de ingrsar datos:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Registrar_FotoActa]
@nombre varchar(50),
@fotoActa image
as
begin
insert into FotosActa (nombre, fotoActa)
values (@nombre, @fotoActa)
end
```

Así tengo la clase donde esta mi modelo de datos de la tabla que ya enseñé antes:

```
public class FotosActa
{
   public int idFotoActa { get; set; }
   public string nombre { get; set; } = null!;
   public byte[] fotoActa { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

No estoy utilizando entityframework, así que el procedimiento almacenado lo declaro creando un método, con la conexión a la base de datos:

```
public bool RegistrasActas(FotosActa fotosActa)
{
    try
    {
       this.Conectar();
       this.com = new SqlCommand("Registrar_FotoActa", cadena);
       this.com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       this.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", (object)fotosActa.nombre);
       this.com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fotoActa", (object)fotosActa.fotoActa);

       return Convert.ToBoolean(com.ExecuteNonQuery());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
       throw;
    }
    finally
    {
       this.Desconectar();
    }
}
```

Y este es el controlador donde llamo al método donde declaré el procedimiento almacenado:

```
public ActionResult Actas(FotosActa fotosActa)
        {
            MetodosDB metodosDB = new MetodosDB();

            try
            {
                if (metodosDB.RegistrasActas(fotosActa))
                {
                    ViewBag.Guardo = "Se guardo";
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "No se guardo";
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Opinión: No es demasiado optimo guardar datos binarios en base de datos por lo enormes que pueden ser al final, pero es tu decisión. Si cambias de idea, con guardar la ruta y el nombre de cada imagen en tu disco en un campo de texto normal seria suficiente y evitarías el problema actual.

Comment: @masterguru como puedo hacer eso? me podes explicar? Quiero añadir, que estoy usando asp.net core 6

Comment: lo que dice @masterguru es que guardes las fotos en un directorio predeterminado e insertes la ruta del fichero.  Meter fotos en la base de datos lo suelo hacer solo si es un dato principal y no tiene una alta resolución.

Comment: En caso de que quieras meterla, normalmente la metes en formato binario en un campo blob o si el gestor tiene otro tipo de campo específico para fotos

Comment: El problema es que lo conviertes en object (el cual se refiere al componente durante la ejecución en otra ejecución del programa, los mismos datos pueden generar un object diferente). tienes que convertir en binario el campo y el nombre a string

Comment: Si me dices cual es el gestor de base de datos te lo arreglo para que te funcione con las dos versiones.